Is it common to only get detailed estimates from contractors after signing a contract?
Is it normal for contractors to discuss a job with you, give you a verbal estimate of the cost of the job, and refuse to write a detailed written estimate unless you agree to the job? I've been looking into increasingly extensive/expensive projects at my home (think siding, windows etc.). Contractors come by and discuss the project with me, and so far my outcome this time is 1 ghost, 1 company providing me a detailed estimate a few days later like I would expect, and 2 contractors giving me their prices right there and expecting me to agree on the spot. When I push back for a written estimate so I can look it over and get back to them, they insist that they will write out the contract after I agree to the bid. When I verbally ask them about the scope of the work, we seem to be in agreement, but nothing is written (for me to review anyway). These instances were both involving the company owners coming to my home to price out the job. I thanked them for their estimates and told them I would consider it and get back to them. They're now following up with me asking for an answer, but I still have no written quotes from them.
I understand drafting a detailed estimate is time consuming work. But these are not small or simple projects I'm looking to get done. We're talking $40k+ here. Am I unreasonable for expecting a detailed estimate at this stage? These are all relatively large, well-established, and well-reviewed companies I've called.

If they won't give you a detailed estimate, pass them by.  If an otherwise good contractor  is pressing you for your commitment but won't put anything in writing tell then you accept their proposal subject to all details being in writing. Then don't sign anything until all details are in writing. This game can go both ways, but the reality is a contract has to be in writing to be binding and enforceable..

record the conversation

Last year I had some more than usual post problems. Regular people did their thing and suggested someone from another department take a look. He spent a lot of time (a couple of hours) climbing in the attic and taking pictures all around etc. Then he have me a number in the thousands for removing insulation, adding new insulation, fixing holes, etc. I said give me a written proposal - just a page with an outline of the work - email or paper, and you've probably got a deal. Never heard back from him. Weeks later get a call from someone else in the company and I told them what I needed. Never

got that one piece of paper - so no deal

If they won't put their money where their mouth is, you shouldn't put your money there either.

A detailed estimate is a trade secret.
The best you can hope for pre-contract is a written quote.
Their propensity to give a written quote is proportional to how much they want the job.

I'm not sure how a scope of work is a trade secret. Estimates don't usually contain processes or specific products unless requested by the customer. I agree with the rest, though.

trade secret = anything you don't want to share with your competitiors

scope of work if it says "paint the exterior walls and doors  at 1313 mockingbird lane: prep, primer and 2 top-coats" is not a  trade secret,  but if it gives the square feet or hours  it probably is.

As a former remodeler and builder I've never done what you describe. There's nothing to agree to without an itemized estimate, so it's absurd to expect you to do so.
However, we're in a different era these days. Conventional business standards started falling away when the Great Recession thinned the ranks of quality contractors, and it's fallen off even more since COVID-19 when more shut down. The lack of interest in the trades by young people doesn't help, either. These days the contractors that remain are in high demand, so they're in a position to call the shots. If you don't agree to their flaky terms, plenty of other desperate folks will be (reluctantly).
Your choice is clear: Keep searching for old-school businesspeople with scruples who are willing to write a proper estimate, or cave to the demands of the greedy and impatient new crop. Best of luck.
